# Python for each faster than for indexed?

Tags: python, for-loop

In python, which is faster?

1

```
for word in listOfWords:
    doSomethingToWord(word)
```

2

```
for i in range(len(listOfWords)):
    doSomethingToWord(listOfWords[i])
```

Of course I'd use xrange in python 2.x.

My assumption is 1. is faster than 2.  If so, why is it?

Comment: You could test it yourself ;). And yes 1 is faster.

Comment: For 2, for each i you calaculate the length of the list. First is faster

Comment: Your assumption is likely correct for the reasons that you've likely guessed -- It can optimize the item lookup in C code.  In both cases, you're calling `next` on a native object so that should be pretty fast either way (although xrange still may need to do more calculating to handle start, stop and stride, etc)... but in the latter case, you then need to do the additional step of _indexing_ the object which you didn't have to do before.

Comment: @Begueradj no, `len(listOfWords)` is only evaluated once.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you very much for the information, i will read more about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of asking this questions, you can always try do them by yourself. It is not hard.
Super simple benchmarking will show you the difference.

```
from datetime import datetime
arr = [4 for _ in xrange(10**8)]

startTime = datetime.now()
for i in arr:
    i
print datetime.now() - startTime

startTime = datetime.now()
for i in xrange(len(arr)):
    arr[i]
print datetime.now() - startTime
```

On my machine it is:

```
0:00:04.822513
0:00:05.676396
```

Note that the list you are iterating should be pretty big to see the difference. The second loop is longer because each time you need to make a look up by index (`arr[i]`) and also to generate the values for `xrange`.

Please do not spend too much time in mostly useless microoptimization, rather try to look whether you can improve the computational complexity of your inner loop functions.

Comment: Using `timeit` would be better

Comment: @glglgl a lot of things would be better. For example telling that such benchmark does not make sense, because a lot of other things are more important that microoptimization. Does datetime do the job? Yes. Does it show what the OP asks? Yes. do I explain why? Yes. Do I tell what to do better? Yes. So the answer is good enough.

Comment: While timeit may be better, I'm choosing this answer as the correct one because he explained why in the answer.  No one else did.  (although someone did in the comment to my question)

Answer (score 5):

Use Python's timeit module to answer this kind of question:

```
duncan@ubuntu:~$ python -m timeit -s "listOfWords=['hello']*1000" "for word in listOfWords: len(word)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.2 usec per loop
duncan@ubuntu:~$ python -m timeit -s "listOfWords=['hello']*1000" "for i in range(len(listOfWords)): len(listOfWords[i])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.1 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

simply try `timeit`.

```
  In [2]:  def solve(listOfWords):
         for word in range(len(listOfWords)):
               pass
   ...:     

In [3]: %timeit solve(xrange(10**5))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.34 ms per loop

In [4]:  def solve(listOfWords):
         for word in listOfWords:
               pass
   ...:     

In [5]: %timeit solve(xrange(10**5))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the speed advantage, 1 is "cleaner-looking", but also will work for sequences that do not support len, namely generator expressions and the results from generator functions. To use solution 2, you would first have to convert the generator to a list in order to get its length *if you could*. But what if the generator is generating the list of all prime numbers, and doSomething is looking for the first value > 100?

```
for num in prime_number_generator():
    if num > 100: return num
```

There is no way to convert this to the second form, since this generator has no end.

Also, what if it is very expensive to create the elements of the list (as in fetching from a database, or remote web server)? If you are looking for a matching value out of a generated set of N values, with #1 you could exit as soon as you found a match, and avoid on average the generation of N/2 values. To use #2, you first have to generate all N values in order to get the length in order to make the range.

There is a reason Python 3 converted many builtins to return iterators instead of lists - they are more flexible.

```
What is Pythonic?
"for i in range(len(seq)):"? No.
Use "for x in seq:"
```